# Stopping a service at specified time

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I'm trying to get this service to stop based on a saved sharedPreferences stop time. As you can see below, mTime is the start time (in milliseconds) to run the pendingIntent from AlarmManager. This code works and always starts my service at the provided start time and listens for an incoming call. The issue is that I don't know where to use the stop time (in milliseconds) to trigger the service to stop/cancel the pending intent.

For instance, say I started the service at 11pm (mTime) but wanted it to stop at 7am (mTime2). It would be ideal if the AlarmManager.set method had a stop time parameter.

**Service**:

```
//set alarm to trigger service
public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn){
    //get shared Prefs time
    Long mTime = SaveSchedulePrefs.getSchedule(context);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, RingerService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if(isOn){
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mTime, pi);   //change current time to shared prefs
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
        pi.cancel();
    }
}
```

Starting the service (this always works based on mTime in the alarmManager.set method):

```
//register listener
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    return START_STICKY;
}

 @Override
   public void onCreate(){
     mContext = (Context)this;
       mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

       mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
           // state change 
           @Override
           public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
             //set ringer stuff
               myRingerManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
               int ringerMode = myRingerManager.getRingerMode();
               if (state == 1){ 
                   try{
                       Log.d(TAG, " number from incoming call: " + incomingNumber);
                       ...etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add an action to the pendingIntent. for example "my.action.start"  or "my.action.stop"

then in the service onStartCommand check the intent.getAction()

```
//Note check for null on the getAction() I'm just typing in code example.

boolean isStart = (intent.getAction().equals("my.action.start")) ? true : false;

   if (isStart) {
        startForeground(R.id.action_record, getNotification());
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    } else {
        stopForeground(true);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: I might be seeing this wrong but how does it fit into the AlarmManager? Would the AlarmManager have to use .set on a second pendingIntent with the end time specified?

Comment: Yes a 2nd pendingintent with the action stop with the end time.  I think you got it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I created a second pending intent with the added i.setAction("stop") and the end time preference variable. The logic you gave as an example works for the most part, except that the first pending intent also needs an action. Without it, the if statement throws a NullPointerException on the else clause.

Comment: You can see that I have a note in the code for the null.  intent.getAction() returns a string then if the string is non null you check the action.  There are of cource many ways to code this good luck